# event.preventDefault() doesn't stop the keypress or keyup events

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom-events, preventdefault

I am trying to fetch aadhar number from the user using a template variable. Since the aadhar is 12 digits long, i need to show spaces after every 4 digits. Additionally, since aadhar number contains only digits, i have created a function `numberOnly()` to stop the user from entering anything else other than digits. Below is the code i have written:

**index.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <mat-label>Enter Aadhar Number</mat-label>
    <span class="text text-danger">*</span>
    <input matInput #aadharInput (keypress)="numberOnly($event)" (keyup)="checkSpaces(aadharInput)" maxlength="14" [value]="aadharInput.value">
  </div>
</div>
```

**index.ts**

```
numberOnly(event){
    if(this.aadharNumber.length==12){
      event.preventDefault(); //doesn't stop the default behavior
    } else {
      let charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
      if (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) {
        this.aadharLength = this.aadharLength + 1;
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  }


  checkSpaces(aadharInput:HTMLInputElement){
    if(this.aadharLength==4 && aadharInput.value.length<14){
      aadharInput.value=aadharInput.value+' ';
      this.aadharLength=0;
    }else if(aadharInput.value.length==14){
      event.preventDefault()  //doesn't stop the default behavior
      for(let i = 0; i< 14; i++){
        if(aadharInput.value[i] != ' '){
          this.aadharNumber=this.aadharNumber+aadharInput.value[i];
        }
      }
      this.isAadharValid(this.aadharNumber);
    }
  }


  isAadharValid(aadhar:string){
    console.log("aadhar is: ", aadhar);
    console.log("aadhar length is: ", aadhar.length);
  }
```

What i want to achieve is that when the length of `aadharNumber` becomes 12, `keypress` or `keyup` events should not be triggered which is why i have placed the `event.preventDefault()` functions in the condition check. However, after entering 12 digits in the input field, whenever a digit key is pressed, the value of aadharNumber gets updated and the length keeps on increasing becoming `24, 36, 48...` and so on.

I also tried using `(keypress)="$event.preventDefault()"` in the html which works fine and prevents any input at all. So, as per my understanding, since calling `numberOnly()` is not the default behavior of `keypress`, it doesn't work the way i want it to. So how do i stop the `keypress` or `keyup` events when `aadharNumber`'s length becomes 12?

Comment: are you sure `this` is what you think it is in that code?

Comment: @JaromandaX i didn't understand your question. Are you asking if the context is changing with every call?

Comment: Is the value of `this.aadharNumber.length` what you expect (i.e. are you sure you are calling the `preventDefault` method)?

Comment: @mgarcia yes, the value of ```this.aadharNumber.length``` becomes 12 when i enter 12 digits in the input element.

Comment: Does your code work if you only call `event.preventDefault()` inside the `numberOnly` method?

Comment: @mgarcia yes, it does work with only ```event.preventDefault()``` inside the ```numberOnly()``` method

Comment: Mmm, if you `console.log` the value of `this.aadharNumber` just before calling `event.preventDefault`, what does it get logged?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212974/discussion-between-samarth-saxena-and-mgarcia).